# screen snipping program leaves left over square after snip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm attempting to resolved an issue with a left over square after my snipping program is done snipping. I would like to delete any instance of the square drawing after the initial snip

[image].

Steps to replicate:

Select "mode" > select "snip" > drag rectangle and take a screen snip

Select "mode" > select "snip" > now observe the previous snip still has the rectangle on the screen (as shown in the picture)

My code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PIL import ImageGrab
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.topMenu()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Lil Snippy")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("assets/lilSnippyIcon.png"))
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 300)

        # QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
    def topMenu(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        saveAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/saveIcon.png"), "Save", self)
        saveAsAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("assets/saveAsIcon.png"), "Save As", self
        )

        modeMenu = menubar.addMenu("Mode")
        snipAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/cameraIcon.png"), "Snip", self)
        snipAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F1"))
        snipAct.triggered.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        videoAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/videoIcon.png"), "Video", self)
        videoAct.setShortcut("F2")
        soundAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/audioIcon.png"), "Sound", self)
        soundAct.setShortcut("F3")
        autoAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("assets/automationIcon.png"), "Automation", self
        )
        autoAct.setShortcut("F4")

        optionsMenu = menubar.addMenu("Options")

        helpMenu = menubar.addMenu("Help")
        helpAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/helpIcon.png"), "Help", self)
        aboutAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/aboutIcon.png"), "About", self)

        fileMenu.addAction(saveAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(snipAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(videoAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(soundAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(autoAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(helpAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(aboutAct)

        self.snipper = SnippingWidget()
        self.snipper.closed.connect(self.on_closed)

    def activateSnipping(self):
        self.snipper.showFullScreen()
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.hide()

    def on_closed(self):
        self.show()

class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 2

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        self.hide()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img.save("snips/testImage.png")
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        self.closed.emit()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        trans = QtGui.QColor(22, 100, 233)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        trans.setAlphaF(0.2)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(r)
        r_path = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r_path)
        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans.setAlphaF(0)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        qp.drawRect(r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset `self.start_point` and `self.end_point`:

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
    self.hide()
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
    img.save("snips/testImage.png")
    QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
    self.closed.emit()
    self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
    self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()
```